# React Native: Use state in screenOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to build an edit mode toggle, but am a little stuck trying to handle the actual toggle.

Set up simply like this:

```
const CrewAddEditScreen = (props) => {
    const [isEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(false);
    ...
```

And I want to handle the toggle via a header button like this:

```
export const screenOptions = (navData) => {
  return {
    headerRight: () => (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title="Edit"
          iconName="md-create"
          onPress={() => {
            isEditMode ? setIsEditMode(false) : setIsEditMode(true);
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
  };
};
```

But currently I get a "can't find variable: isEditMode" error. How do I access it in this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your code to Snack or simple add all code here.  It would be helpful for solving your problem

Comment: There's nothing else in my code that relates to the  issue I'm describing. I just need to be able to change state using setIsEditMode when tapping a custom header button as I've shown above.

Comment: There's no way for the navigation header to directly access the screen's state. You need either a global state (redux), a context or an event listener. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: No, seems like overkill for this scenario when I could just move the button into the component. Perhaps I'll just do that for the moment if it's that much of an effort to do that in the nav header.